# No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version - none of the answers provided have helped

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, provisioning, ios-provisioning

I renewed my developer license and figured out that my private key was on my other laptop in India so I created new certificates and accidentally updated my iOS to the latest version and there is no green light next to iPhone device in organizer window and i am getting this error, I am on XCode 4.2 - "No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination" There was also no option to "Use for development" when I clicked on the device.

1. I have revoked my certificates and also made new certificates
2. Cleared the certificate history.
3. Restarted XCode and also my iPhone.
4. Installed the certificates in my library as well

None of the above has helped! Any clue/help would be appreciated

Comment: which version of ios have your device. and which version's SDK contain your xcode

Comment: Can you go to build settings, search for deployment target, and see how far you can crank that setting down?  Maybe you're targeting an iOS level higher than your phone has.

Comment: My iPhone has 6.1.3 and in xcode I can go to maximum 5.0

Comment: just update your xcode

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your xcode after that it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your Xcode to 4.5 (new) version. And after that for run previous iOS you have to add SDK for previous version from `Xcode > Preference > Download > Component` there you can see various simulator for iOS 4.3, iOS 5.0, ios 5.1, and iOS 6.0. Download this simulator and you are good to go.

Answer (score -1):

Hi the solution is simple...
You need to add a device click SHIFT + CMD + 2 and add devices

in IOS6 you need to click on menu -> windows -> devices and add it

.
- click on the left corner side on the project
- click info
- in the Deployement target 
- in the IOS Devewlopment Target click the version available for you system